SVG circle stroke small radius
I create a svg library for my software using only svg outline and no fill. That way I can easily adjust appearance and color.
However, I am facing difficulties with small dots. I prefer using the <circle /> element for it as I can adjust the size of the dots. Using different scales and rendering softwares, I sometimes though get the circles with a hole inside, which I would expect to be fully filled.


<svg stroke="currentcolor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<circle cx="18" cy="12" r=".5"/>
<circle cx="12" cy="12" r=".5"/>
<circle cx="6" cy="12" r=".5"/>
</svg>






You are using stroke-width="1.5" with a circle radius of  r=".5" . Try  using a maxim stroke-width of 2*r, in this case 1

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942666/space-between-svg-stroke-and-fill (tl;dr: stroke wider than (half of the) radius creates overlap, that may or may not be subtracted from the drawn area.)

Thank you @enxaneta! However, while this is the reason, it is not the solution to the problem. I would like to keep my stroke width consistent through my icons and keep the dots as small as they are.

Thank you for the reference @myf! The accepted answer of this actually solves my problem.

@TimNikischin Glad it helped! Yet I would be very cautious, since that stroke-linecap="round" ; stroke-dasharray="whatever" feels a bit hack-y to me. I'd advise sticking to "sane" stroke-width values, if possible. Also, be careful when using teeny-tiny viewports and circle strokes, especially if you need any interactivity, since it may turn into a minefield in real-world implementations; did some research on that lately: https://myfonj.github.io/tst/SVG-decimal-precision-results.html

Thank you very much @myf! This might be worth commenting on the related answer. However for my implementation it shouldn't be a problem, as I embed those svgs as css background image and expect the full css related DOM element to be clickable.

Made me finally ask about teeny-tiny (viewport) problematic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78692079 and got some valuable insights.
