Formal limits or baseline of decimal precision in SVG implementations
I have tested some very basic SVG sample (stroked circle filling square viewport with dash-array producing quarter slices) in varying viewBox dimensions, and observed some spectacular rendering and behavioural discrepancies across implementations, which -- while somewhat expected along the lines of thought that 'there will inevitably be some floating point precision loss involved somewhere' -- happened surprisingly early, either in rendering or in calculated "interactive hit-box" of the rendered shape.
I have skimmed though SVG specs several times, whether there are at least some guideline or non-normative note about how much "scalable" the SVG world has to be without losing precision to be baseline compliant, but didn't find any stance about that.
I understand that the spec might be deliberately "murky" about this, putting my questions in "it depends" territory, but anyway. My questions are namely:

Is (was) there ever such guideline (be it formalized or even merely discussed), ordering implementers for what dimensions they have to produce interoperable outcome and from what values on they are allowed to diverge?
If there was, where can we read that?
If not, would it make sense to open this topic in the working group?
Does it make sense to fill bugs for implementers with ridiculously large/small values in STRs (today)?

Exploration and results
Think this super-simple SVG with viewBox size of 1:


svg { max-height: 80vmin; }
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 viewBox="-.5,-.5 1 1">
 <circle r=".25"
  stroke-width=".5"
  pathlength="4"
  stroke-dasharray="1,1"
  stroke="currentcolor"
  fill="none"></circle>
</svg>



 
One would probably expect to get the first variant (as we do get some implementations), rather than the second (as we do get in others).
Making length and coordinate values in the sample exponentially larger or smaller gives us a simple way to try different "scales" that should theoretically yield same result. Yet real-world testing revealed that anything above e+5 (10_000 × 10_000 viewBox) and below e+2 (200 × 200 viewBox) produced error in at least one implementation, be it shape rendering or hit-box area calculation.
Full results / Testing playgound / Embedded playground:


const ua = navigator.userAgent;
const isFx = !!ua.match(/\) Gecko/);
const FxFreezesBeyond = -9;
let allowFreeze = false;
let dotsPerLine = 10;
let halt = false;
function render () {
 clearDots();
 dotsPerLine = 10;
 const n = in_d.valueAsNumber;
 if(isFx && !allowFreeze && n < FxFreezesBeyond) {
  if(confirm('This may freeze your browser.\n\nReally proceed?')) {
   allowFreeze = true;
  } else {
   in_r.value = in_d.value = FxFreezesBeyond;
   return
  }
 }
 const exp = `e${n>0?'':'+'}${-n}`;
 out_exp.textContent = exp;
 let html = eval('`' + in_template.value + '`');
 for_svg.innerHTML = html;
 for_code.value = html; 
 const numDecimalDisplay = n > 0
  ? Number(`1${exp}`).toFixed(n)
  : `1${'0'.repeat(-n)}`;
 for_info.innerHTML = `
  1${exp} == ${numDecimalDisplay}
  UA: ${ua}
 `;
 paint()
}
render()
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', 
function(event){
 el_dots.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',makeDot(event));
}
);
function makeDot(e, size=1) {
 const t = e.target.tagName;
 let colour = 'black';
 if(t == 'circle') colour = 'lime';
 if(t == 'svg') colour = 'black';
 if( colour == 'black') return '';
 return `<span style="
  position: absolute;
  width: ${size}px;
  height: ${size}px;
  top: ${e.clientY-size/2}px;
  left: ${e.clientX-size/2}px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: ${colour};"></span>`;
}

function clearDots(){
 el_dots.innerHTML = '';
}
onresize = clearDots;
function paint(){
 clearDots();
 const s = document.querySelector('svg');
 const bb = s.getBoundingClientRect();
 const size = (bb.width-1) / dotsPerLine;
 if(size < 1) size = 1;
 let buff = '';
 for ( let y = bb.top; y <= bb.bottom ; y += size ) {
  for ( let x = bb.left; x <= bb.right; x += size ) {
   buff += makeDot(
    {
     target:document.elementFromPoint(x, y),
     clientX: x,
     clientY: y,
    },
    size
   );
  }
 } 
 el_dots.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', buff); 
 dotsPerLine *= 2;
 if(dotsPerLine > (bb.width + size)/1) dotsPerLine = 10;
 in_paint.value = `raster ${dotsPerLine}^2`
}
html {
 overflow: scroll;
}
textarea {
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 30ch;
 height: 40ch;
 white-space: pre-wrap;
}
body {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
 gap: 1em;
 @media (max-width: 40ch) {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
 }
 & > .inputs {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0; 
 }
 & > .outputs {
  flex-basis: 50vw;
  flex-shrink: 1;
 }
}
input[type="number"] {
 width: 8ch
}

input[type="button"] {
 padding-inline: 1ch;
}

#in_paint {
 display: none;
}
label:has(#in_hitbox:checked) + #in_paint {
 display: block;
}
body:has(#in_hitbox:not(:checked)) #el_dots {
 opacity: 0;
}
<section class="outputs">

<div id="for_svg" style="outline: #0FF6 solid; "></div>
<pre id="for_info" style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word;"></pre>

</section>
<section class="inputs">

<label>
 Dec. places
 <input id="in_d" type="number" value="0" min="-99" max="99"
  oninput="in_r.value=value;render()">
</label>
<input type="button" onclick="in_d.value--;in_d.oninput()" value="-">
<input type="button" onclick="in_d.value++;in_d.oninput()" value="+">
<br>
<input id="in_r" type="range" min="-9" max="9"
 oninput="in_d.value=value;render()">
<br>
<label><input id="in_hitbox" type="checkbox" checked>Show hitbox</label>
<input id="in_paint" type="button" onclick="paint()" value="paint">
<details><summary>Template (<code>${exp}</code> = '<span id="out_exp"></span>')</summary>
 <textarea id="in_template" oninput="render()">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 viewBox="-1${exp},-1${exp} 2${exp} 2${exp}">
 <circle r=".5${exp}"
  stroke-width="1${exp}"
  pathlength="4"
  stroke-dasharray="1,1"
  stroke="currentcolor"
  fill="none"></circle>
</svg>
<style>
 circle:hover { color: highlight; }
 circle:active { color: mark; }
</style>
</textarea>
 
</details>

<details open><summary>Code</summary>
 <textarea id="for_code" oninput="for_svg.innerHTML=value"></textarea>
</details>

</section>

<div id="el_dots"></div>



Excerpts:
Showing rendering (black) and computed hit-box (half-transparent green) from three SVG engines, where at least one "fails". The correct outcome is present in the leftmost e+6 cell.

(...)


Your link indicates you're primarily interested in browsers. Now browsers exist to render HTML and CSS and are optimised for that. They also implement SVG and MathML and canvas but those account for less than 1% of content.
When implementing SVG etc in a browser, we have to work within the limits set by the requirements to support HTML and CSS in the most efficient way possible and those limits are not necessarily best for implementing SVG.
You can raise browser bugs if you like about range but we probably won't fix them. In Firefox we have this selection amongst others...

bug 876479
bug 1500521
bug 1684895
bug 1167959
bug 1611284

Other browsers have similar reported issues.

Thanks for the answer, I hoped you would catch it here. I understand there are pragmatic implications of statistical usage of given technology, and yes, web platform interests me the most at this point, but I am not sure if I understand correctly how exactly is concrete platform related to the question? What I wanted to address was more like "for what e+? values exactly are implementations allowed to render <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1e+4,-1e+4 2e+4 2e+4"><circle r=".5e+4" stroke-width="1e+4" stroke="black" fill="none"/></svg> in other way than sharp black disc"?

What does it matter what's allowed if that can't/won't be implemented for perfectly valid reasons. If your head hurts when you bang it against the wall, don't ask for all walls to have padding, instead stop hitting your head against walls.

From my point it could matter, because telling "such sample should be crisp for such values" (implying "below this value it can become blurry mess or disappear or whatever") would set a baseline telling me 1) whether reporting a bug when "not rendered crisp" makes sense 2) how should we author SVGs, to avoid rendering problems.


Feel free to report any bugs, they may be fixable but don't be too disappointed if they aren't 2) avoid really large or really small numbers. Browsers resolution is 1/60th or 1/64th of a pixel and maxes out at maybe 20,000px or so.


That actually sounds like pretty good rule of thumb, thanks! This piece of information would probably make sense to promote more in docs or even mention in or near the specs, at least as a side note (?) You now seeing sentences like You're simply using numbers that are too small. might be quite scary for programmers (looking at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1684895#c1 )
